# "the first fit with u variable does not work" in segmented package in R

Tags: r

I want to do segmented relationships in regression models as below.

```
test <- clogit(y~x+strata(RN_INDI, method ="exact", df)

os <- segmented(test, ~x)
```

However, it doesn't work.

```
Error: the first fit with u variable does not work..
```

Please help me on how to solve the error.

Comment: 1. The code on your question contains a syntax error (missing closing parenthesis). 2. Provide a (sensible) starting value for the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.  However, I modified it as below, but the same error occurs.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test <- clogit(y~x+strata(RN_INDI), method ="exact", df)


os <- segmented(test, ~x, psi=10)

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I don't believe the segmented package supports clogit models.